# Ubuntu One Installer Win 7 Cannot find My Ubuntu One Account

Tags: installation, ubuntu-one, authentication

When I run Ubuntu One installer on Win 7 Home Premium it gets as far as the screen that asks to log in with and existing Ubuntu One account or to create a new Ubuntu One account. When I enter my email and password it returns an authentication error stating that it does not recognize my email. This is odd because I can log in with the same credentials from my browser or other devices. I even went so far as to cut and paste the credentials into my browser to verify they worked there. Then I cut and pasted from the same location into the Ubuntu One installer -- that failed as before.

Any suggestions? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Windows part of https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-am-i-getting-an-the-authentication-failed-error-on-windows-225/ - it wants you to open https://one.ubuntu.com/ in Internet Explorer or Google Chrome then restart your computer and try to setup Ubuntu One again. This will download and install the proper certificate as a workaround.

We have a new version that should be released soon which fixes the problem you are seeing. It will use certificates that are bundled with the installer rather than depending on Windows to have this certificate installed.